# Set Positions returns E_NOTIMPL

Tags: directshow

> I want to write only a specific portion of a .avi file in the output .avi file .For this I  follow Source Filter ->Avi mux->File Writer.I try to use IMediaSeeking on the Mux to set the specific start and stop times using Set Positions but it  returns E_NOTIMPL.
>   I also try to query the graph builder for IMediaSeeking and try to set the start and stop positions with no success.Can someone help?

Comment: Is the IMediaSeeking::SetPositions call on the IGraphBuilder returning E_NOTIMPL as well?

Comment: Thanks for the comment.I got it solved.I had to add a splitter also to the above graph.

Answer (score 1):

Query for IMediaSeeking on each of the output pins connected to the mux inputs, and set the positions on those.

Comment: Well I try to do exactly as you say 
Source(Async Reader)->AVI Splitter->AVI Mux->File Writer. But when I try to find the second output pin("Stream 01") it returns an error.If I implement graph without connecting this pin IMediaSeeking on the Stream 00 runs S_OK but there is no clipping that takes place.